# User sessions aren't maintained in Website using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication

We have a website displaying some strange behaviour.  It was just updated from ASP.NET v2 running on IIS6 to .Net v4 running on IIS7.5.

It is only used within the intranet and uses Windows Authentication, but the user sessions do not appear to be maintained as I would expect.

The situation is this:
Person A logs in - all good.
Person B logs in - all good.
Person A refreshes their page, and they are now logged in as Person B.
Person C logs in, and now Person A & B are both logged in as Person C.

We are getting the current logged in user by way of 
`System.Security.Principal.IIdentity winId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;`

I'm kind of baffled as to what's going wrong here.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the site use any form of OutputCache?
Could be related to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163577.aspx#S2

Comment: We don't use OutputCache, but I'll try turning it off in the config just in case.

Comment: Do you have <sessionState mode="InProc" /> ?

Comment: Yes, we are using InProc.  But I'm waiting for approval from the system owner to raise a Change Control so we can switch it over to a StateServer.

Comment: Just in case anyone's interested, changing to run off of the stateserver seems to have resolved the problem.